# why image background color is showing me blurry when I crop the image using PHP?

Tags: php

I am using following php function to crop a image. When a image is cropped then the image background is look like a blurry. Like bellow image. It's should be solid white background color :

**Blurry Image :**

[image]

Php code is bellow :

```
function crop_image ($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {    

    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }

    $filename = $newcopy;
    $thumb_width = $w;
    $thumb_height = $h;
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $original_aspect = $width / $height;
    $thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;
    if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
    {       
       $new_height = $thumb_height;
       $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
    }
    else
    {       
       $new_width = $thumb_width;
       $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
    }
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );    
    $color = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $color);

    imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                       $image,
                       0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                       0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                       0, 0,
                       $new_width, $new_height,
                       $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 80);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're feeding a `$quality` value of 80 into [`imagejpeg`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). [JPEG is a lossy format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression). This results in artifacts like the ones you're seeing:

> quality is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75).

Try using a higher value:

```
imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 90);
```

The maximum value for `$quality` is 100.

Comment: OH let me do this.